# Restrict the value based on the value in other connected cell (both dependent on the same list)

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A:$A"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

I have this VBA code which selects the dropdown values from list in sheet 2.
What I need is the following:
 Now the options shown in "A2" cell's dropdown should be all but A001 i.e. except the one that has been already selected above...And similarly with all the other dropdowns in the first column.
[image: Check this image out!][image: This too]

Comment: How many entries are in your original a001, a002, ... list?

Comment: They can be any fixed number..Here they are 999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>I'm going to put all of the components on a single worksheet; e.g. Sheet2. While my own sample data holds 19 *A001, A002, ... etc.* entries, this should work for any number of entries providing you have filled the array formula in column Z down sufficiently.</sub>

1. In an unused column (like column Z) to the right, put this array formula into the second row.

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(A$3:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A)), MATCH(0, IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A$3:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A)), C:C, 0)), COUNTIF(Z$1:Z1, A$3:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A))), 1), 0)), TEXT(,))
   ```

Confirm with CSE and fill down to capture every entry in column A.

2. Go to Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager and create a new defined name like **dv_list** with workbook scope using the following formula as the *Refers To:*,

   ```
   =Sheet2!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$Z:$Z, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(Sheet2!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$Z:$Z, MATCH("zzz", Sheet2!$Z:$Z)))/SIGN(LEN(Sheet2!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$Z:$Z, MATCH("zzz", Sheet2!$Z:$Z)))),1))
   ```
3. Select C1:C9 and use Data, Data Tools, Data Validation to create a List type Data Validation with `=dv_List` as the *Source:*.

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks but  the first step yields nothing on column Z. Can you explain a little more on each step?

Comment: Read my narrative. You are going to have to translate my example into your own multiple worksheet scenario.

Comment: After first step, should I get the values in the Z-column? I am not getting anything over there.

Comment: Can I get an insight into how you went about thinking  on this? I mean the formulas are pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

I was rerouted here for my question being a "duplicate" but I'm not following the example above on how I would accomplish the following:

This question already has an answer here:
Restrict the value based on the value in other connected cell (both dependent on the same list)  1 answer

I have a drop down list of the following:

Max85k, Max110k, Max125k, Max150k, Max175k

These refer to the max amount that can fit into these buckets.

If the amount that is listed in another cell on my sheet is $105k for example, I don't want the Max85k selection to be allowed. If the value is 83K for example then all of the selections would be allowed b/c that amount could fit into any of the buckets. If the value was 135k then only the max150k and max175k selections would be allowed. Etc Etc.

Is there a way to do this?